# Issue importing createRoot from "react-dom" in React on Rails

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, react-dom, react-on-rails

I am trying to create a React on Rails project for the first time. I have

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react_ujs": "^2.6.2",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
```

And I am trying to create a router (as per the tutorial [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-rails-project-with-a-react-and-redux-front-end-8b01e17a1db/))

```
import React from "react"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

import PropTypes from "prop-types"
class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => ('home') } />
          <Route path="/hello" render={() => <HelloWorld greeting="Friend" />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

The error I keep getting is `Warning: You are importing createRoot from react-dom which is not supported. You should instead import it from react-dom/client. "rails"`

I have researched this thoroughly, and there are many explanations on how to solve it for pure react, but none about react on rails as far as I can find. One suggestion was to deprecate the react-dom version, but it was obviously highly disrecommended. Can anyone tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone solved it for me:

The tutorial is using outdated syntax. The correct syntax should be something like:

```
import React from "react"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<h1>Hello World</h1>} />
          <Route path="/hello" element={<HelloWorld greeting="Friend" />} />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

using `element=` instead of `render=` and without the function `() =>`